# Hibernate - Spring - Avoid rollback

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to insert data in two different table. After insert in the first table (save1 function) I start an cycle for  on array String where foreach element i call save2 function. In the save2 function maybe raised an ConstraintViolationException. I've annotaded method as can you see with Transacational.

I would that exception raised in method save2 not propagate rollback for save1 method. Is it possible?

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, value = "transactionManager")
public class MyService extends BaseService {


    public void insert(AppFileForm appFileForm) {
        try {
            _insert(appFileForm);
            setStatusOk();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            setStatusKo(msg.getProperty("file.upload.error"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            setErrorFromException(e);
        }
    }

    public void _insert(){
        save1();
        save2();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void save1(){
        for(String s: myArray){
            save2();
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void save2(){

    }
}
```

The dao method are irrilevant

```
public void save(MyClass mc) throws Exception{
    em.persist(mc);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Transactional` annotation has no effect when called from another method of the same component.

Comment: Then I need to put all persist action  in same method?

Comment: You should restructure your code in such way that all transactional methods are called from the outside to guarantee the transactionality. This means that the method save2, which should open a new transaction, must be decleared in a different component and used in the current one.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.